# to enroll iphone developer program, can the supporting site just a blog

Tags: iphone-developer-program

i dont have any personal website so can i still enroll the iphone developer program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.  You don't actually need a website.  I enrolled as an individual without a website.